# Какой путь у файла?

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь найти файл в своем проекте при запуске файл равен null.Какой путь фала должен быть. Файл называется questList.txt

```
File File = new File("questList.txt");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: File File = new File("questList.txt");

Comment: файл создается в андроидном приложении и искать его надо в том устройстве, где запущено приложение, а не в исходниках. Файлы, которые вы в ворде создаете, сохраняются тоже у вас, а не в майкрософте, где лежат исходники ворда.

Comment: Файл дожен быть одинаков у всех ,он не должен меняться в зависимости от устройства. И как же его тогда найти?

Comment: никто и не говорит, что файл меняется. Еще раз перечитайте, что написано в моем комментарии.

Comment: Вам нужно файл в resources/raw положить и доставать через ресурсы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Файл должен находится в папке src/main/assets.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод readAsset() вернет содержимое questList.txt файла

```
System.out.println("---------------------" + readAsset());

public String readAsset() {
    String string;
    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("questList.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        string = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return string;
}
```